# File Upload wrong filepath

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I'm trying to upload video on youtube using [this code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video)

I have changed `var filePath = @"REPLACE_ME.mp4";` by

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    var filePath = FileUpload1.FileName; // Replace with path to actual movie file.

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
        videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
        videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

        await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error that it's wrong path
[image]

How can I solve that?
Another I have tried:

```
var filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
var filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ToString();
var filePath = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

but same result..

Comment: If you do _not_ provide a full path, the system uses the current path of your application, which is obviously IIS Express, running on `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express`. Solution: Provide a full path before saving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to Save the file first using:

```
var newFile = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(newFile);
```

Or as your working with the FileStream class you could always try:

```
FileUpload1.FileContent; // gets the file as a stream
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have do this:

```
Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
```

[Controler.Server Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Web.Mvc.Controller.Server);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

EDIT:

or just use the stream like this if you do not necessarily have to save the file localy:

```
youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", FileUpload1.FileContent, "video/*");
```

Comment: same result. And how i know Server.MapPath is for files which is in the server. I want to upload files by client

Comment: Oh, my bad sorry. If you just want to get the file stream I would use the FileUpload1.FileContent property this way you don't have to save the file localy first.